# proftpd - find client ip on server while connection is alive

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd

I need to get the get the client IP from a specific connection from proftpd on linux (where I know the pid). I have searched in the /proc/ dir but wasn't able to to get any information about the IP.

Does anyone know a method how to get or where to find this information?

p.s. sorry, but i forgot to mention that all this should happen from inside a FUSE implementation, so is it possible to get that information without using an extern programm or is there maybe a library that could help me doing that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you later added that you want to do that from C program would be to directly ask Proftpd. Just set your Proftpd instance so it's saving [scoreboard file](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_ScoreboardFile.html). You can then parse that file directly (which made you depending on format of internal file of Proftpd), or you can parse output of command `ftpwho -v -o oneline` which is Proftpd's command using scoreboard file to output different kinds of information about connected users.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `fuser` tool. It allows to identify files and sockets opened by a process. That should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `netstat -tnp` command, it will show all TCP connections + IP + PID of process behind that connection. You should also be able to find the client IP in Proftpd logfiles.

Comment: thank you. i forgot to mention that i need this information in a c-programm. i editet my question to make this clear. thanks you for that fast answer.